# Can "gyroscopic" be rephrased as "circular path"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, terminology

I would like to know the best term to use instead of the word "gyroscopic". In English dictionaries, they usually explain the physics meaning behind the gyroscopic phenomenon which I find really weird.

In the [Longman English Dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/gyroscope), the definition is

> a wheel that spins inside a frame and is used for keeping ships and
>   aircraft steady. It can also be a child's toy.

At [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gyroscope), the definition is

> an apparatus consisting of a rotating wheel so mounted that its axis
>   can turn freely in certain or all directions, and capable of
>   maintaining the same absolute direction in space in spite of movements
>   of the mountings and surrounding parts: used to maintain equilibrium,
>   determine direction, etc.

In the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/), the definition is

> Pertaining to or of the nature of the gyroscope; rotatory.

For me, the aforementioned definitions are unclear from a linguistic perspective. It is hard to visualize the meaning from the above definitions. When I read the root of [gyroscopic in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyroscope), which is

> A gyroscope (from Greek γῦρος gûros, "circle" and σκοπέω skopéō, "to look")

I found this explanation more interesting since it explains the path that wheel travels in, which is circular. Understanding the word from the linguistic meaning helped me a lot to grasp and visualize the meaning behind this phenomenon; therefore, my question is whether I can rephrase "gyroscopic" as "the circular path phenomenon" to reflect the meaning from a physics point of view.

The gyroscopic phenomenon is explained from a physics perspective in this video of [Gyroscopic Precession](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ty9QSiVC2g0). Once the guy starts spinning the wheel, the rotation of the wheel around the rod is clearly a circular path, hence the gyroscopic phenomenon.

Comment: What language are you trying to translate it into?

Comment: @NathanTuggy, to English since the "gyroscopic" is the pronunciation of the Greek word.

Comment: @CroCo; But "gyroscopic" *is* English...

Comment: @Stephie, I am aware of it but as I said it is the pronunciation of the Greek word which means it is not the literal translation like numerous words in physics (eg inertia which means being lazy).

Comment: @CroCo: But it has long ago assumed a specific meaning related to the context of physics/mechanics. So while it's good to know the origins, they will not always suffice to properly convey the meaning. I recomend checking out the origins of diabetes for example.

Comment: @Stephie, which is better for understanding the concept saying gyroscopic or merely the circular path to describe the trajectory of the moving body for normal English speakers? I believe the latter is more clear.

Comment: @CroCo: I can assure you that it is not clear at all. Native and fluent English speakers will know what a gyroscope is; they will not know precisely which sort of circular path you are talking about, nor what characteristics you refer to. (See my edited answer for examples of the confusion.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy, "Native and fluent English speakers will know what a gyroscope is" they know it from schools not from its linguistic meaning which means students memorize it.

Comment: @NathanTuggy, "they will not know precisely which sort of circular path you are talking about" yes it is true but physics here explains that by using newtown's laws to explain why the wheel moves in a circular path.

Comment: @NathanTuggy, don't get me wrong. I'm not here to argue rather to try to understand why a lot of words are not translated literally if that possible or makes sense.

Comment: @CroCo: Because there are simply too many technical concepts (especially given the way English is used as the general language of science these days) to allow them to be phrased in general terms. Whether you're talking about cache pollution (computer science), externalities (economics), or angle of attack (aerodynamics), technical terms tend to take on far more nuances and specific implications than their etymology would suggest. So yes, you have to memorize the terms.

Comment: The first two definitions are for "gyroscope" not "gyroscopic"...

Comment: *Gyroscope* and *gyroscopic* are English words.  Sure, they may be loanwords, but so are lots and lots of other English words.  Once we've borrowed a word, we keep it :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the title needs to indicate "proper definition" rather than "proper translation", since that is what being asked. Translation questions are off-topic; the definition question is more of a physics one and not an English language one.

Comment: @user3169, " Translation questions are off-topic" why there is translation tag then? I'm not asking about the definition. My question is clear what is the proper translation for the original Greek word that gyroscopic is derived from.

Comment: See [**What topics can I ask about here?**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Ideally, someone would need to be conversant in both languages to try to answer that. I don't see the actual Greek word in your question.

Comment: @user3169, I've included the link for the Greek word in my post.

Comment: @CroCo They may know what a gyroscope is from school, but the key part is that they know what a gyroscope is. If they don't know what a gyroscope is, the best approach is to explain what it is and then use the term "gyroscope" instead of trying to cram an explanation into every sentence where you refer to the phenomenon.

Comment: Google and Wikipedia give an alternative definition of γῦρος as "turn" or "rotation" which makes more sense to me in this context than "circle."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proper term, in English, for the gyroscopic phenomenon is "gyroscopic". Like many technical terms, its meaning is not accurately or precisely understood from simply knowing its etymology. The gyroscopic effect is inherently a term for a phenomenon of physics; that's why it's generally defined in terms of physics.

Attempting to refer to it as "circular path" or the like is too vague and general to be understandable by others, unless you explain to them what you mean, in which case they will say "well, why didn't you just say 'gyroscopic' then?" For example, the same phrase could refer to the practice of making roads or tracks spiral up steep hills, to the sideways pull felt when a car goes around a sharp corner at high speed, or (in the context of aviation, a common use for gyroscopes) to a great circle route. None of those are related to gyroscopes at all, or to each other.

Paraphrasing in terms of what you yourself understand can often be helpful for learning at first, but those paraphrases won't necessarily reflect what others will easily understand. So rather than making a habit of saying to yourself, "Oh, this English word means *such-and-such*", you should work toward understanding it without translating or paraphrasing at all.

Answer (score 5):

## No

First off, those definitions you listed are for '[gyroscope](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gyroscope)', not '[gyroscopic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gyroscopic)'.

A [gyroscope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyroscope) is a specific type of object, which has a lot more properties than being circular. Specifically:

> A gyroscope is a spinning wheel or disc in which the axis of rotation is free to assume any orientation. When rotating, the orientation of this axis is unaffected by tilting or rotation of the mounting, according to the conservation of angular momentum. Because of this, gyroscopes are useful for measuring or maintaining orientation.

So, although some parts of the gyroscope are moving in a circular path, that is not nearly enough detail to describe a gyroscope.

'Gyroscopic' is an adjective that indicates that something is similar to gyroscope, but not in *what way*. The thing which is gyroscopic may not even be spinning, but is instead used for navigation, *like a gyroscope*. The few uses of the word 'gyroscopic' (which I'm not sure I've ever even heard before) I can find searching the internet refer more to the [stabilizing effect](http://science.howstuffworks.com/gyroscope1.htm), which is *caused* by spinning, but is not *itself* the process of spinning.

So, no, "circular path" is not - in general - an acceptable substitute for "gyroscopic", even ignoring the fact that the word is an adjective, and the phrase is not adjectival.

Perhaps there are certain situations and usages for 'gyroscopic' that are referring to nothing more than the spinning aspect of a gyroscope, in which case you could possibly use a phrase related to "circular path" to simplify things. However, we would need to see a specific usage in order to determine if the substitution was appropriate in that case.